# Are there any books/papers talking about inner product on vectors over finite fields?

Tags: finite-fields, inner-products

Are there any books/papers talking about inner product on vectors over finite fields? In particular, I'd like to learn things on $F_p^n$, or simply $F_2^n$. I read some proofs using the inner product on $F_2^n$ in some papers, but I can only understand the general ideas. However, since it's possible that $v\cdot v = 0$ even if $v \neq 0$ for some $v\in F_2^n$, I don't know how they exclude this special case in their analysis. And I have no idea whether there are some other special cases should be considered. I also have some other concerns, so I think maybe I should read some related stuffs to so as to fully answer all of my concerns.

Comment: You can't really exclude vectors orthogonal to themselves. There are entire subspaces that are orthogonal to itself. Actually in some contexts maximal such subspaces are interesting! The so called self-dual codes are well studied such beasts. Anyway, this means that inner products are more or less unrelated to any notion of length and/or distance. Characteristic two is a very special case. The basic theory of general bilinear forms and related quadratic forms over finite fields is explained in Lidl & Niederreiter (as well as in many other books). That could get you started.

Comment: In fact, even in $\Bbb R^n$, one can consider indefinite inner product spaces (that is, vector spaces endowed with nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear forms), which likewise have nonzero vectors $v$ with $v \cdot v = 0$. These are quite interesting in themselves, and show up in relativity and various special geometries.

Comment: I don't wanna exclude the case that vectors orthogonal to themselves. I just want to know if there is such a case, why the proofs are still correct. For example, in the proof, they say because the matrix $A\in F_p^{k-1 \times k}$ has rank at most $k-1$, the null space of $A$ has rank at least 1, so there exists $j$ such that Aj = 0. In this case, it's possible that j is equal to some row vector in A and $j\cdot j = 0$. In this case, the matrix multiplication involves inner product, so why it still correct in terms of the rank of A and null(A)? This is one of many aspects I wanna know.

Comment: In one of the proof, I just see that they treat $j\cdot j = 0$ as a special case and exclude that case, but it seems that there is not too many explanations for it, or it's obvious, but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Ok. Your comments make it clearer. Matrix multiplication is really about the theory of linear transformations from one vector space to another. That theory works over any field. If you review linear algebra, you see that concepts like: linear (in)dependence, basis, generated subspace, rank-nullity theorem et cetera only rely on the laws of field arithmetic. Special properties of the reals enter the scene only when geometric aspects: lengths, angles, orthogonal projections and such are discussed. It is very good that you ask and think about these things!

Answer (score 2):

Recommend [Gerstein](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-90), who has an ongoing interest in forms over finite fields $F$ as well as rings $F[t]$

Answer (score 2):

There is lots of literature on "inner products" on vector spaces over finite fields.  Though they are not called that, because you cannot rule out vectors being self-orthogonal, and you don't have a notion of positive/negative, distance, etc.

They go under the name of bilinear/sesquilinear forms (also related to quadratic forms); you can also find details of the geometries, known as finite polar spaces.  These have many interesting connections to finite simple groups.  They are also related to important families of distance regular graphs

I think a good book to start with is Grove's Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra, for a good algebraic description.  These notes by Peter Cameron are also good, although challenging:
http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/pps/